# Need help in understanding simple function approximation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]
[image]

Why does the underlined statement hold? How can $s_n$ approximate $f(x)$? Will $nK_{F_N}$ approach $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Definition:
[image]

Comment: There is a typo since equation (49)  should be $\sum_{i=1}^n$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^n$. Suppose you rank-order the $c_i$ so that $c_1 < c_2 < ... < c_n$.  Can you describe $\mu\{ x \in X : s(x)> c_i\}$?  Or $\mu\{x \in X: s(x)>y\}$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$?  [It is weird that Definition 11.13 defines "measurable" after it is used in your underlined sentence.]

Comment: The sets $\{x|\ f(x)>a\}$ are the union of those $E_i$ for which $c_i >a$. If each $E_i$ is measurable, so is their union. Conversely, if $s$ is measurable, then (by renaming if necessary) assume the $c_1,...,c_n$ are ordered in increasing order. Then $E_n=\{x|\f(x)>(c_n+c_{n-1})/2\}$ is measurable. Then $E_n\cup E_{n-1}=\{x|\ f(x)>(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2})/2\}$ is measurable. But then $E_{n-1}=(E_{n}\cup E_{n-1})\cap E^_{n}^c$ is measurable too. Here we used that $E_n$ and $E_{n-1}$  are disjoint. Continue with the same idea to shot all $E_i$ are measurable.